# How do I use pyautogui on Virtual machine?

Tags: python, virtual-machine, attributeerror, pyautogui

I have a piece of the code that works just fine on my PC:

```
updated=0
while updated==0:
      w=pyautogui.getWindows()
      lw=list(w)
      if strg in lw:
          time.sleep(1)
      else:
          updated=updated+1
          time.sleep(0.1)
          pyautogui.press('enter')
          break
```

But when I run it on Oracle's VM VirtualBox, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'getWindows'
```

I tried reinstalling PyAutoGui and looking for files with the same name, but it didn't work. Can someone help me solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the difference between your PC and the VirtualBox, check on both:

1. Path to the module
   `print(pyautogui.__file__)`
2. Version of the module
   `print(pyautogui.__version__)`
3. Available methods/attributes of the module
   `print(dir(pyautogui))`

It's possible you could use
`pyautogui.getAllWindows()`
instead of
`pyautogui.getWindows()`

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I was using two different versions of PyAutoGui and the correct attribute for the newest version is getAllWindows().

Comment: Yeah, in version 0.9.39 it was 'getWindows', from 0.9.40 it's 'getAllWindows'.